# Configuration for Redis cluster

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-5.1

I'm running Laravel in a GlusterFS cluster, and I want to setup a redis cluster too. I'm not able to find out how should I configure Laravel.

This is the example config file:

```
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => false,
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
],
```

How can I add multiple servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you just add another server there and update the `cluster` boolean:

```
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => true,
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],
    'secondary' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'password' => 'p@ssw0rd',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],
],
```